# Does a Lua 5.1 Assembler Exist?

Tags: assembly, lua, vm-implementation, opcodes

I've been studying the Lua 5.1 VM opcodes for some time now, out of boredom.

And I want to try coding something!

So is there any existing way to assemble Lua Assembly into Bytecode ?

Answer (score 2):

I never used it, but I've found this link in my "Things to watch when I have more time" list (oddly I never get to the part of consuming this list...)

http://chunkbake.luaforge.net/

It claims to assemble Lua 5.0 VM Code into bytecodes, not 5.1, and unfortunately I don't know how much has changed from 5.0 to 5.1.

Comment: I don't know what's changed either, and I'm really looking for v5.1

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I never used it either, but [ChunkSpy](http://chunkspy.luaforge.net/) is a Lua 5.1 *disassembler*, and on that site there is also a file explaining both the 5.0 and 5.1 opcodeset. So maybe, starting on that code, you start writing an assembler yourself?